# Получить значение из массива по последовательности его ключей

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs

Столкнулся с ядрёной задачкой, потратил много часов, перерыл весь интернет, решения не нашёл, и все мои попытки как то это решить оказались очень далеки от правды - обращаюсь к вам.

Имеется многомерный массив (массивы в массиве) с уровнем вложенности более 3. Назовём его **arr**.

Если я заранее знаю какое значение я хочу достать, я пишу что-то вроде `arr[0][2][1][4]` и получаю это значение. Но как получить это значение, если у меня есть **последовательность уровней вложенности** в переменной, например это **x="0,2,1,4"** - и как теперь достать значение из **arr** используя **x**?

В идеале нужно не просто достать значение, а изменить (его и только его), чтобы в результате выполнения функции получился массив точно такой же как был на входе, единственным отличием должно быть это изменённое значение.

Вот работающая реализация - самое ближайшее, к чему мне удалось подобраться. Это ужасный костыль, и я верю что это можно сделать правильнее.

[image: костыль]

Объясняю как работает этот код - мы разбираем последовательность ключей массива на отдельные ключи, потом в зависимости от количества этих ключей вручную добавляем дополнительные квадратные скобки с значением ключа к массиву. Должен же быть другой способ это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для таких случаев существует понятие как рекурсия.

```
function findFieldByIndexes(array, path){
  let first = path.shift();
  return path.length > 0 ?findFieldByIndexes(array[first], path): array[first];
}
```

ну и вызов

```
 findFieldByIndexes(arr, path.toString().split(","));
```